# Objective c text field with delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I'm learning objective c and need help to understand delegate.

I have a UITextField in the FirstViewController and I want to show the text inputed in the SecondViewController.

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *accessButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *codeField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *getCodeString;

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CodeField;

@protocol CodeFieldHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

@property NSString *saveCodeString;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *candidateLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CodeFieldHandlerDelegate> myDelegate;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

<CodeFieldHandlerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize getCodeString;
@synthesize secondViewController;
@synthesize saveCodeString;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)accessButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    //get the input data from text field and store into string
    getCodeString = self.codeField.text;

    //go keypad back when button clicked from textfield
    [self.codeField resignFirstResponder];

    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; 
    secondViewController.myDelegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}

// name of this string is the same of the NSString in the delegate
- (NSString *) saveCodeString {
    return getCodeString;
}

@end
```

And SecondViewController.m

```
 #import "SecondViewController.h"

 @interface SecondViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation SecondViewController

 @synthesize candidateLabel;
 @synthesize myDelegate;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.candidateLabel.text = [myDelegate saveCodeString];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Is the `saveCodeString` method called? Is `getCodeString` set to the expect value? Is `self.candidateLabel` set to a non-nil value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are performing a segue to the `SecondViewController` the wrong way. Have you got the segue from `FirstViewController` to the `SecondViewController` working?

Try this:

```
secondViewController = (SecondViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR STORYBOARD NAME" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER"];
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. The segue from FirstView to SecondView works fine. I've tried your solution but still I can't see the text inputed in the FirstViewController in the candidateLabel in the SecondViewController

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine explained to me that delegate is not the best option for my purpose. So here is my final code working with some changes for the benefit of understanding:

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameUser;

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameUser2;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)nameField:(id)sender {

    self.nameUser = self.nameField.text;
    [self.nameField resignFirstResponder];

    // check if it works
    NSLog(@"Your name is: %@", self.nameUser);

    //in the main.storyboard create a segue 
    //from FirstViewController yellow icon to the 
    //SecondViewController and name it like: goToSecond

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToSecond" sender:sender];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToSecond"]) {

        SecondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.nameUser2 = self.nameUser;
    }
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameLabel.text = self.nameUser2;
}

@end
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I saw you found another way, but anyway, you had to change `getCodeString` to `strong`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *accessButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *codeField;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) NSString *getCodeString;

@end
```

Comment: You don't use both `strong` and `retain`. `strong` is for ARC and `retain` is for MRC.

Answer (score -1):

Did you set delegate of UITextfield in storyboard ??

or try set delegate in

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController`<UITextfieldDelegate>`

if still problem exist. please provide link to source code ,i like to look into it.

Comment: 1) You can see the delegate being set in the OP's code. 2) Adding the protocol to the `@interface` line is only for compiling. And it is not in any way related to setting the delegate.